# Filtering Django admin console rows based on the logged-in user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to restrict which rows appear in the Django admin console based on the user that is logged in. Using the AuthUser model, I have created the following Account model which links Django user accounts to specific businesses in my database:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    username_id = models.ForeignKey('AuthUser', db_column='username_id')
    business_id = models.ForeignKey('Business', db_column='business_id')
```

Here is my Business model:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

When the user logs in, I want to restrict the user so they can only add/view/delete entries into/from my database (through the Django admin console) for their respective business. Here is my Entry model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    business = models.ForeignKey('Business')
    entry_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Is there an easy way to get this accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

In your model admin, you could override the method `get_queryset()`.

So you could do something like,

```
 class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      def get_queryset(self, request):
          qs = super(EntryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
          if request.user.is_superuser:
              return qs
          return qs.filter(business__in=request.user.account_set.all().values_list('business_id', flat=True))
```

The last line, `qs.filter(business__in=request.user.account_set.all().values_list('business_id', flat=True))`, filters the initial queryset(which defaults to all entries).

`request.user.account_set.all()` returns all the `Account` objects associated with the user. Yes, the way you design your `Account` model will allow multiple objects to be associated to a User. If you want to limit it to one, you should consider using `OneToOneField`.

Appending `.values_list('business_id', flat=True)` to the queryset is telling Django that you only want specific columns to be returned, in this case just the `business_id` column. `values_list` returns a list of tuples but if you only need one column from the queryset, you can pass the keyword argument `flat=True` which will return a flat list.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is exactly happening on this line: return qs.filter(business__in=request.user.account_set.all().values_list('business_id', flat=True))

Comment: @foadster, added the explanation above.

Comment: If I replace MyModelAdmin with admin.ModelAdmin, things work. I login to the console, try to add an entry, but can still choose a business to submit an entry as. If I try to change an entry, I get "'User' object has no attribute 'account_set'"

Comment: @foadster, updated the answer with the correct one. With regards to the account_set, I think you need to update your `Account` model. The `username_id` field should be an FK to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Comment: Oh ok. I had it set to the 'AuthUser' table, with the column pointing to username_id. Now I get '(1054, "Unknown column 'U0.username_id_id' in 'where clause'")'. I can still add entries as different businesses.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening but I guess removing `_id` in the `username_id` field might fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah it didn't fix it...just now says the same thing but username_id.

Comment: How come I can still add entries as different businesses?

Comment: That's a different question. You need to override the admin form used in creating and/or editing entries.

Comment: Ok no worries. I'll have to learn how to do that. Thanks for your help.